# Открыть таблицу в QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, xlrd

Как открыть таблицу в QTableWidget с помощью модуля xlrd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

Считываем данные:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('book.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets() [1]
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range (sheet.ncols)]for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

Добавляем данные в `QTableWidget`:

```
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mytable = QtGui.QTableWidget()

# если нет заголовков, то следующие три строки можно удалить
headers = data[0]
data = data[1:]
mytable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

for row, columnvalues in enumerate(data):
    for column, value in enumerate(columnvalues):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
        mytable.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать